# Trouble understanding proof that linear map $T$ is normal if and only if $\lVert Tv\rVert=\lVert T^*v\rVert$ for all $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm having trouble understanding the last step in the proof given in Axler's LADR. He proceeds as follows:

[image: The theorem the proof of which I'm having trouble with]

Here (7.16) is the following:

[image: The theorem used]

I don't understand 2 things:

a)Do we even need (7.16) to establish the 2nd equivalence? By definition of normality and $T$ being normal (from the statement of the theorem), $T^*T-TT^*$ is the $0$ operator and hence the inner product is equal to $0$ (because it is a product of a vector with $0$). I don't see what the point of (7.16) here is. And even if it were, how exactly WAS it used? The property says that if the operator $S$ is self-adjoint (in our case $T^*T-TT^*$) and $\langle Sv,v\rangle$, the operator is $0$. Well the operator is already established to be $0$ by $T$'s normality and $\langle (T^*T-T^*T)v,v\rangle=0$ as a consequence of that, so what's the intent here?

b)It is completely unclear to me how the final equivalence is established (i.e. how we get from $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle$ to $\lVert Tv\rVert^2=\lVert T^*v\rVert^2$

Comment: For the reverse implication, we don't yet know that $T^*T-TT^*$ is zero.

Comment: As the author says, both directions of the proof are being done at the same time i.e. alongside showing that $T$ is normal implies $||Tv||=||T^*v||\forall v$, the author is also proving the converse: that $||Tv||=||T^*v||\forall v$ implies that $T$ is normal. As for your second, question - in the expression $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle$, denote $Tv$ by $a$, so you have $\langle T^*a,v\rangle$. Now recall that, by definition, we must have $\langle T^*a,v\rangle=\langle a,Tv\rangle$. Substitute back in $Tv$ for $a$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh, alright, it clicked into place for point a), thanks. What about b)?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 I stupidly did not think to apply the defintion of the adjoint to $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle$ , it all makes sense now, thank you

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 This was such a stupid question to post, should I delete it?

Comment: @V.Ch. You don't have to. You can leave it up. You can answer it yourself. You can try closing it. Ultimately, it is up to you. In the broader scope of things, I don't think "stupid" questions like these hurt anyone. You learned something, at least. Maybe future readers will have the same 'aha' moment you did just reading these comments (or, if you so choose to, reading an answer you yourself posted). Just don't dwell over this being a "stupid" question. It's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @Cardioid_Ass_22 for the complete answer in the comments:

> As the author says, both directions of the proof are being done at the same time i.e. alongside showing that $T$ is normal implies $||Tv||=||T^*v||\forall v$, the author is also proving the converse: that $||Tv||=||T^*v||\forall v$ implies that $T$ is normal. As for your second, question - in the expression $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle$, denote $Tv$ by $a$, so you have $\langle T^*a,v\rangle$. Now recall that, by definition, we must have $\langle T^*a,v\rangle=\langle a,Tv\rangle$. Substitute back in $Tv$ for $a$.